# Add multiple strokes to Leaflet geojson feature path

Tags: leaflet, d3

Wondering if it's possible to add multiple strokes to a polygon or line feature (the same thing could apply to multiple fills for polygons too).

The leaflet documentation on the [L.Path style options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) doest seem to suggest there is a way.  For example, styling the stroke once is straightforward:

```
var geoJsonFeature = L.geoJson(data, {
  style: {
    color: '#ff9700',
    weight: 4
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

... but it doesn't appear to allow adding a second, thin stroke on top (e.g. with a thinner weight, so the two are strokes are layered one on top of the other), w/o, I guess, loading the geojson twice.

Is it possible to hack this somehow?  Or might it be possible with another library like d3.js?

Comment: Import the same feature twice, with different names. Then style as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is currently possible in leaflet. I'm not sure about d3 either because I've never used it. If it was my project I would create two functions: one that creates the base layer styling and one that adds the secondary layer on top.

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment?